# Passing an array pointer into a function

Tags: c++, arrays, pointers

I have a `Node* hands[4];` and want to pass it into a function called Deal like `Deal(deck,hands,4,"one-at-a-time",13);`

When I use the following function...

```
void Deal(Node *deck, Node *hands[], int num_hands, const std::string &type, int num_cards)
```

I get this...

```
/tmp/ccqckP1I.o:main.cpp:(.text+0x82a): undefined reference to `CutDeck(Node*, Node*&, Node*&, std::string const&)'
/tmp/ccqckP1I.o:main.cpp:(.text+0xb34): undefined reference to `DeleteAllCards(Node*&)'
/tmp/ccqckP1I.o:main.cpp:(.text+0xb3f): undefined reference to `DeleteAllCards(Node*&)'
/tmp/ccqckP1I.o:main.cpp:(.text+0x1030): undefined reference to `DeleteAllCards(Node*&)'
/tmp/ccqckP1I.o:main.cpp:(.text+0x103e): undefined reference to `DeleteAllCards(Node*&)'
/tmp/ccqckP1I.o:main.cpp:(.text+0x104c): undefined reference to `DeleteAllCards(Node*&)'
/tmp/ccqckP1I.o:main.cpp:(.text+0x105a): more undefined references to `DeleteAllCards(Node*&)' follow
/tmp/ccqckP1I.o:main.cpp:(.text+0x1348): undefined reference to `CutDeck(Node*, Node*&, Node*&, std::string const&)'
/tmp/ccqckP1I.o:main.cpp:(.text+0x1492): undefined reference to `CutDeck(Node*, Node*&, Node*&, std::string const&)'
/tmp/ccqckP1I.o:main.cpp:(.text+0x15dc): undefined reference to `CutDeck(Node*, Node*&, Node*&, std::string const&)'
/tmp/ccqckP1I.o:main.cpp:(.text+0x1726): undefined reference to `CutDeck(Node*, Node*&, Node*&, std::string const&)'
/tmp/ccqckP1I.o:main.cpp:(.text+0x1870): undefined reference to `CutDeck(Node*, Node*&, Node*&, std::string const&)'
/tmp/ccqckP1I.o:main.cpp:(.text+0x1c2d): more undefined references to `CutDeck(Node*, Node*&, Node*&, std::string const&)' follow
/tmp/ccqckP1I.o:main.cpp:(.text+0x1f8c): undefined reference to `DeleteAllCards(Node*&)'
/tmp/ccqckP1I.o:main.cpp:(.text+0x1f9a): undefined reference to `DeleteAllCards(Node*&)'
/tmp/ccqckP1I.o:main.cpp:(.text+0x1fa8): undefined reference to `DeleteAllCards(Node*&)'
/tmp/ccqckP1I.o:main.cpp:(.text+0x1fb6): undefined reference to `DeleteAllCards(Node*&)'
/tmp/ccqckP1I.o:main.cpp:(.text+0x1fc4): undefined reference to `DeleteAllCards(Node*&)'
/tmp/ccqckP1I.o:main.cpp:(.text+0x1fd2): more undefined references to `DeleteAllCards(Node*&)' follow
/usr/lib/gcc/i686-pc-cygwin/4.7.3/../../../../i686-pc-cygwin/bin/ld: /tmp/ccqckP1I.o: bad reloc address 0x1b in section `.text$_ZNSt11char_traitsIcE7compareEPKcS2_j[__ZNSt11char_traitsIcE7compareEPKcS2_j]'
collect2: error: ld returned 1 exit status
```

Comment: You probably just want a `std::array<Node, 4>`.

Comment: @chris This is for a Data Structures homework assignment and I have to use the Node* [].

Comment: Well, that sort of sucks then. The pointer looks useless at first glance, just introducing unneeded complexity, and an array that knows its size doesn't really make anything easier, just safer. As mentioned, the first is one option for correct syntax.

Comment: Please don't replace a question with a new one, it makes existing answers pointless.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The following prototype (the first variant you mentioned) is correct:

```
void Deal(Node *deck,
          Node *hands[],
          int num_hands,
          const std::string &type,
          int num_cards);
```

when used for example like this:

```
Node n;
Node* deck = &n;
Node* hands[4];
Deal(deck, hands, 4, "one-at-a-time", 13);
```

just note that `hands` in this case is just an array of pointers that don't point to any instances of `Node` yet. Make sure they point to valid objects before you try to use them:

```
for (int i = 0; i < num_hands; ++i)
    hands[i] = new Node();
```

Comment: I used my first option, and for some reason I get a list of undefined references to methods when I try to compile.

Comment: @JonathanWrona: Edit your question, copy-paste the errors your compiler gives you and copy-paste the lines that compiler complains about.

Comment: Oh, how could I pass `Node* hands[4]` by reference so I can directly edit the data?

Comment: You are already passing it in a way that changes are visible to the caller. You are passing an array of pointers, your function modifies these pointers (elements), not the array itself.

Answer (score 0):

```
Node [] *hands
```

...should be

```
Node* hands[]
```

or

```
Node** hands
```

Answer (score 0):

One of the solutions is

```
Deal(Node *deck, Node **hands, int num_hands, const std::string &type, int num_cards)
```

You can call as you have in your example.